# Generated package name wrong in Eclipse after using maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have some dtd file from which I am trying to create Java source files. I am using `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to do so. (version=0.14.0) I have defined `generatePackage` element as `com.abc.practice.myxml`. And my `generateDirectory` element is set to `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java/myxml`.

Now what is happening is the sources are generated, but the package name ends up being `myxml.com.abc.practice.myxml` in Eclipse. This results in compilation error as it is looking for the package `com.abc.practice.myxlm` which does not exist!

Now I have three such schemas to create Java sources from. So if I set my `generateDirectory` to `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java` only then it only updates the first schema. I have defined three different `execution` elements with `configuration` inside each of these, of cource.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: please share the whole `maven-jaxb2-plugin` configuration. Eclipse version? Eclipse plugin `m2e-wtp JAX-RS` version?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Luna (Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1). I do not see anything named `m2e-wtp-JAX-RS` version. `maven-jaxb2-plugin` version is 0.14.0. The groupid of the plugin is `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2`.

Comment: can you update to the newest version of eclipse?

Comment: No this is what I have to do with. As I have other child projects too which might get affected.

Comment: there should be a m2e plugin installed which adds the generated-sources/* folders as source folders. try to update the plugins. i tried it in eclipse oxygen and there it is working.